# Is there a way I can bulk remove part of a filename for 900ish files?

Tags: windows, rename, naming

Need a way to remove parts of a filename.

Have tried some Basic notepad++ stuff lol

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mjqT.jpg

Image shows mainly what I need!

e.g

sevenberry_island_paradise-SB-4131D1-4-S5090015(.jpg)
to
sevenberry_island_paradise-SB-4131D1-4(.jpg)

The item codes are after the SB-, e.g 4131D1-4, everything after this I don't want.

Any way of removing this from all these files would be a huge huge huge help!!

Thanks!!

Comment: This question has been asked (and answered) here several times before. Please spend some time searching before asking a new question. Start by refining your search using more information, such as the scripting or programming language you're using, as part of your search expression.

Comment: I don't know any coding really I can just take directions, I've tried what I've looked for already like: 

get-childitem *.jpg | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("-S*", "") } doesn't seem to work

Comment: The code you posted in your comment needs to be in your original question, so we know what you've tried and so we can help you figure out what is wrong **with the code**. This is not a place for you to ask someone else to invent a solution to your problem, it's a place where you can get help with **your own solution**.

Comment: Not knowing any coding isn't an excuse for not searching for an existing answer here. We're not a free coding service, and there is existing code here you can use for a starting point. We're more than happy to help, but you're expected to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first, and part of that effort is the search for existing answers and an attempt at using code you find from the results of that search to do what you need. Once you've done that and run into problems, you can come back and ask for help. Good luck.

Comment: So I've found this that sort of works but why is it removing the .jpg?

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.jpg" | % { Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName -replace '-S5.*\.jpg$', '') }

Comment: Hey I figured it out with my own tiny braincell!

Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.jpg" | % { Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName ($_.FullName -replace '-S5.*', '.jpg') }

Ty!

Comment: This was actually incorrect for doing 850 files, but for some reason worked in seperate folders, Lmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not appropriate as posted and you need to post what you have tried and ask for help with your own code and any error messages or unexpected results you encounter. That being said, I see your problem and it seemed like fun to figure out a solution so I have done that.

This code will find all the files inside the specified directory (you can add the `-Recurse` parameter to the `Get-ChildItem` line to get the files in all subdirectories too) and rename them all, removing the end of the file name using RegEx.

**Make a copy** of your files before trying this. I have tried my best to create a solution that will work for the file names that you pictured, but if the file names are very different than what is pictured then you may have unintended results. **Take a backup first.**

```
# Specify the path in which all of your jpgs are stored
$path = 'C:\Path\To\Jpgs'
# Get all of the files we want to change, and only return files that have the .jpg extension
$jpgs = Get-ChildItem -Path "$path" <#-Recurse#> | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq '.jpg'}
# Perform the same steps below on every file that we got above by using foreach
foreach ($jpg in $jpgs) {
    # Store the original file name in a variable for working on
    [string]$originalBaseName = "$($jpg.BaseName)"
    # Use RegEx to split the file name
    [string]$substringToReplace = ($originalBaseName -split '-[0-9]+-')[1]
    # Re-add the '-' to the string which you want to remove from the file name
    [string]$substringToReplace = '-' + $substringToReplace
    # Remove the portion of the file name you want gone
    [string]$newBaseName = $originalBaseName -replace "$substringToReplace",''
    # Rename the file with the new file name
    Rename-Item -Path "$($jpg.FullName)" -NewName "$newBaseName$($jpg.Extension)"
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks, yeah I'm running into some problems with it right now, lol, it added jpg onto the end of it and didn't remove what I needed in some cases :s I will try this code now! Thanks

I actually have no clue what to change in all that, do I need to change [string] ? Lol

Comment: Oh nice, it adds an extra . onto the filename though? so it looks perfect but then it's ..jpg?

So now I just need to find out how to remove 1 dot and leave the other? I think I can do this lmao

Comment: That was a mistake on the second to last line. Try it again now.

Comment: I just removed the . after newbasename!! Thanks so much! Can I ask how it finds out how to split it from the correct - ?

Comment: The line that says '-[0-9]+-' is what does that. That's a regular expression that looks for one or more numbers 0-9 surrounded by hyphens, which happens to be unique to that part of the file name of all your files. Go plug one of your file names and that regular expression into regexr.com and that will explain it in detail

Comment: So it splits AFTER it finds "-29-" in "sevenberry_classic_plaids-SB-51010D208-29-S4440009.jpg" ? What is that [1] after the expression?

Comment: The split operation produces two strings (the parts before and after the split). The [1] references the second string (in programming 0 is typically the first item in a collection) which is the part after -29-

Comment: Oooooooh ok, so if I wanted to remove what's before that I would just do [0] I guess? Ty so much btw this is a huge help! I'm going to play around with it a bit and see if I can't understand it a bit more so I can change it up because I'll probably get another few hundo files just like these to do eventually, lol.

Comment: That would be a little different because the script is written to cater to that end part of the file name. You would probably want to use [0] and remove line #12 because you would end up with a file name with a '-' at the beginning otherwise.